# Having trouble accessing properties of a javascript return function

Tags: javascript

```
function getCurrentUIValues() {
  return {
    amount: +(document.getElementById("loan-amount").value),
    years: +(document.getElementById("loan-years").value),
    rate: +(document.getElementById("loan-rate").value),
  }
}
```

I am trying to access the property values by;

getCurrentUIValues.amount;

This gives me undefined even with the "loan-amount" field holding a value e.g 5000

I am working with a simple loan calculator and trying to grab user input. I cannot change the way the code is written as I want to understand how to do it this way and its part of the exercise for school. However I am always getting undefined. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access the property on the *function* itself.

You need to access the property on the *return value* you get when you *call* the function.

```
getCurrentUIValues().amount;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!